# Format C# code with js/ts (VSCode extension developement)

Tags: formatting, vscode-extensions

**Subject**: I am rewriting an extension for special language. It's like XML with embedded C#, JS and CSS.

**Problem**: I used external extension API as C# formatter, but now it's deprecated and even removed from marketplace because [OmniSharp C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) now covers all the needs of formatting. But I didn't find any text formatting in the code of this extension to request for similar API.

**Question**: what is best way to format pieces of text as C# inside VSCode extension? Or is there any free JS library for formatting actual version of C# language?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/format

Comment: @LexLi, how can I use this in VSCode extension?

Comment: You have several options to go and only you can tell which might be the best. 1) Ship `dotnet-format` executable with your extension (in the same vsix). 2) Ask your extension users to download it. Once such is installed, shell execute `dotnet-format`. A lot of extensions do the similar things, and either approach has been widely used.

Comment: I thought about this way, but it didn't seem to me like a good idea. Thanks, I'll figure it out